# GrapeAPI + JSONAPI Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I have related resource to be loaded with grape api ?
I'm using ActiveModelSerializers 0.10 and I'm doing something like this in the api:

```
present region, include: ['courts']
```

I get the relationship but I can't get the included array along with the data.

Comment: using render instead of present should do the trick